# Java can't find or load main

Tags: java, compilation

I have recently installed canopy (i don't know if this has anything to do with java)
i have set to system variables the path to javac and java
i was writing compiling and running java programs normally until now that it keeps telling me it can not find or load main class.class
example of code:

```
    class Hello {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    }
```

what is happening?

ok i changed hello to Hello

i run at powershell:

```
   javac Hello.java
   java Hello.class ( i am in the directory of the file)
```

> Error: Could not find or load main class Hello.class

Comment: Try changing chass name from `hello` to `Hello`. And show how are you compiling this program

Comment: ...and what command you are using to run it.

Comment: Try 'java Hello' instead of Hello.class ;-)

Comment: can i say i am sorry now or it doesn't matter? :\ Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run your program using

```
java Hello
```

and omit the .class extension

Comment: Thanks. i was programming a week in python and i forgot java :)

Answer (score 0):

That should compile fine which Java compiler are you using? Make sure to always save and compile your program before running it.